# exclude variables with no variation during prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining

I am working on a binary classification problem.

I do have certain input categorical variables such as `gender`, `ethnicity` etc.

But all the records have the same value. Meaning, all 10K records in my dataset have `female` as gender value. Same for ethnicity as well.

Is it okay to straight away exclude these variables during model building?

Or it is important to retain them? Since, there is no variation (in these variables between output classes), I assume they will not be contributing anything to the output.

Can help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You have only females in your dataset, **adding gender feature** to the model input **will not improve** it.

The technical explanation on why it won't help changes between models, but the intuition is simple - the model tries to find correlation between the features and the labels, and **the correlation** between any variable and a fixed-value variable **is zero**.

You didn't directly asked about it but it worth mentioning that if the classification problem is related to the gender, the model will work better on females than on males because you don't have data about them. That will be true whether you will add those features or not.

I talked about the gender feature as an example, but the answer is valid to any other feature.

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help.

Comment: May I also check, do you know any auto-ml solution that will take care of transforming all input categorical variables into encoded variables for use in logistic regression? I can create a seperate post